# function add custom fields to media gallery

Tags: plugin-development, functions, media-library

I know this has been asked before but I'm having trouble with it and this seems poorly documented.

### My goal:

Create a function that adds multiple custom fields into each item in the media gallery.  What I ideally want is that:

- these would only show on audio media items
- these fields would be things like "lyrics", "cover artist", "original artist" so would be ideal if these can appear under the built in Metadata tab on the audio [Fig 1]
- they would also appear in the quick view along with the other metadata. [Fig 2]  The code that works already does this but I want to retain this function.

### Website details

My website is a wordpress v5.6.2 website with a handful of fairly popular plugins: Content Control by Code Atlantic, Filebird by Ninja Team, Ultimate Member by Ultimate Member, UpdraftPlus backup/restore by Updraftplus.

### What I've tried

I've tried a few things, these don't work for me:

- https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-attachments--wp-31100 - this tutorial seems excellent, in-depth, and answers my need, but after reading it through several times, and playing with the code a fair amount, I simply can't get it to work in any way.
- [Add custom field to attachments in a specific category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227965/add-custom-field-to-attachments-in-a-specific-category) - this seems good but again, I can't get it to work even after playing with it a bit.
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/attachment_fields_to_edit/ - I've scanned the official documentation but haven't found any detail that indicates how to define a field for only one media type.
- [Official documentation for attachment form fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264909/official-documentation-for-attachment-form-fields) - This is a good breakdown of the functions but doesn't answer my question.
- https://gist.github.com/igorbenic/25de6609eb2ac2557ff48771d6118a4f - A good looking github page with some good code on it but again nothing to answer my question.
- [Modify Custom Field in Media Library using JavaScript](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193006/modify-custom-field-in-media-library-using-javascript/193096#193096) - I haven't tried this but it looks concentrated on modifying a field that's already there.
- https://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-add-custom-fields-media-gallery/ - haven't tried, concerned by the clause at the top that says it's out of date.
- [Can I add custom meta for each image uploaded via media-upload.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/can-i-add-custom-meta-for-each-image-uploaded-via-media-upload-php) - doesn't work - or at least, doesn't do what I want.

### Not tried:

I've found these but after all the failed attempts above I'm not sure these are going to be any better!  but for reference:

- https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-additional-fields-to-the-wordpress-media-uploader/
- https://www.kevinleary.net/add-custom-meta-fields-media-attachments-wordpress/

### What does work:

- [How to add a custom field to the media screen (image/gallery)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/298155/how-to-add-a-custom-field-to-the-media-screen-image-gallery) - the top voted answer on this question is the only example I've got to work so far.  It adds a field into every single media gallery item, and I could add some more fields and use it if all else fails but I'd like to get a cleaner solution for this incorporating all 3 points above.  This can be seen on Fig 1 and Fig 2 - the new field called "Style"

Can anyone help me make a function that adds fields in as per my 3x points above?  I'd appreciate an answer even if it only answers 1 or 2 of the points though, I've put them in order of what's most important.

### Screenshots

Fig 1:

[image]

Fig 2:

[image]

Comment: You can use [`wp_get_attachment_id3_keys`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_id3_keys/) to add custom fields into the Metadata metabox, however, you'll be limited to single-line text fields only (i.e. the `<input>` tag). So you should probably just use the `attachment_fields_to_edit` hook, if you want to be able to have other field types like `textarea`.

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks - as you say I do want textarea at least for lyrics.  I will have a look though, it might be worth using this for the other fields.

Comment: The other possible option if you want `textarea` and other field types, is by removing the default metabox and create your own based on the [original source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_id3_data_meta_box/). But I didn't mention that before because you'd still need to use the `attachment_fields_to_edit` hook to add your fields to the "Attachment details" popup in Fig 2, so I thought, "why bother with the metabox"?